# How do you send an id (or hidden field) to a post request in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a post object, and I want the user to be able to edit the object, so my edit page has a URL like viewPost?id=blahblah. Now when I send the post request, how I send the id to the server? I've seen some suggestions online like have a hidden input field with the id in there, but I feel like those are so easy to attack and I'm sure there's a different way.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a URL parameter declared in your route as follows:

```
app.post('/path/:id', function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.params.id);
    next();
});
```

Then post your form to `/path/123` where `123` is the id.

**Note:** Don't forget to sanitize `id` in your route to make sure it doesn't contain a JSON string or anything else that could cause damage.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using handlebars templating engine and you already have the item you would like to edit in the view, your form will look like this:

```
`<form method="POST" action="/items/edit")>
    <input type="hidden" name="item" value="{{this._id}}">
    <button type="submit">Edit</button>
 </form>`
```

**this._id** is the id from the database of the particular item,

This id can be read by the post request by calling its name from the body of the form as below:

```
`router.POST('/items/edit', function(req, res){
    var id = req.body.item;
});`
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: This should be the answer